# Understanding blowups

Tags: algebraic-geometry, blowup

I'm looking for a easy to work with definition of a blowup with an example/someone to check my undestanding of a blowup.

I understand that blowups are a method that we use to deal with singularites of plane curves.

The most famous example is using a blow up to deal with $y^2 = x^3 + x^2$

So with a blow up, we want to blow up a point in affine space $A^n$.

In the example, we have the affine space $A^2$ and we want to blow up a point $(x_1,x_2)$ in this case $(0,0)$

Then we look at the variety space $A^n \times \mathbb{P}^{n-1}, A^n = (x_1,...,x_n),\mathbb{P}^{n-1}=(X_1,...,X_{n-1})$

We take the subset $B = \{A^n \times P^{n-1} |x_iX_j=y_jX_i\}$

I think we call this set of points the blowup.

So in terms of our example,

we introduce $y=tx$ (what is this called)?

Then $y^2=x^3 + x^2 \implies t^2x^2 = x^3 + x^2 \Leftrightarrow x^2(t^2 - x - 1) =0$

From here we get $x^2 = 0 \Leftrightarrow x=0$ and  $y=0$

Also $t^2-x-1=0 \Leftrightarrow t^2 = x+1$

Now this curve $t^2=x+1$ is the resolved curve of $y^2 = x^3 + x^2$ and we have the exceptional curve $x=0$

and this is the blowup of the point (0,0)

Comment: This is all correct, though I should note that since its equation is squared, the exceptional divisor $x=0$ has multiplicity $2$. This is sometimes important to track in computations; for example, it is used to measure how singular the point of interest is (e.g. blowing up the planar triple point $xy(x-y)=0$ we get $x(xt)(x-xt)=x^3t(1-t)$ so that singularity has multiplicity $3$). As for your question about $y = tx$, I don't think there is a standard term; usually people just refer to "new coordinates on the blowup" or something like that.

Comment: Another question I thought of is why does blowing up work? Why does the substition $y=tx$ give us this nice smooth curve with the same tangent directions?

Comment: If you go on and learn about blowups in the abstract, you'll learn that one way to think about blowing up $p \in X$ is "deleting it and replacing it by the projectivization of its tangent space," and $\mathbb P(T_p X)$ has one point for each tangent direction at $p$.